# Python pandas merge rows and convert row values to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert a Pandas dataframe with multiple rows into one row.

Having the following dataframe.

```
key  value   id    code
A     36.0   NWL   787501
B     38.0   NWL   787501
A     19.0   MOH   978462
B     25.5   MOH   978462
A     92.0   PPC   259280
B     73.7   PPC   259280
```

I'd like to convert the dataframe to the following format.

```
A      B      id    code 
36.0   38.0   NWL   787501
19.0   25.5   MOH   978462
92.0   73.7   PPC   259280
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using dataframe reshaping with `set_index`, `unstack`, and `reset_index`:

```
df.set_index(['id','code', 'key'])['value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
key   id    code     A     B
0    MOH  978462  19.0  25.5
1    NWL  787501  36.0  38.0
2    PPC  259280  92.0  73.7
```